# Посчитать количества торговых дней по годам на R

Tags: r

На входе имеется файл по котировкам компании (допустим APPLE) в следующем формате:

[image: Данные по котировкам Apple с 2001 по 2018 годы]

Задача - вывести для каждого из годов количество торговых дней в этом году. Как я понимаю, необходимо сделать data.frame из столбца Date и дальше каким-то образом разбить даты на года, но сделать этого (разбить даты) никак не выходит. Подскажите, как можно решить эту задачу

Answer (score 0):

В вопросе не указан источник данных, а также тип объекта, в котором эти данные хранятся. Рискну предположить, что это объект типа `xts`. Если это так, то решение будет извлечь индекс из объекта `xts`, затем извлечь год и посчитать количество записей.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
table(as.POSIXlt(index(AAPL))$year + 1900)
#> 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 
#> 251  253  252  252  252  250  252  252  252  252  251   61
```

Объект `xts` также можно преобразовать в `data.frame`.

Извлечь год из объекта `Date` можно с помощью функций `format` (`as.integer(format(x, "%Y"))`), `lubirate::year` или способом, приведённым выше.